# Append Remove Button to Array List Item

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, function

I am building a JavaScript to-do list with a function that pushes an input value into an array and appends the value and a remove button to a list element. I have implemented a remove function and, after trial and error and studying other similar demos on this site, it appears that both the initial expression "var lastid = 0" and the increment expression "lastid=+1" enable the click of a specific button to result in the removal a specific list item. Otherwise, without that expression, clicking a remove button for a specific list item results in the removal of the uppermost item in the array list, instead of the item I am targeting. Could someone perhaps explain to me what it is about the initial expression "var lastid = 0" and the increment expression "lastid=+1" that enable the remove function to target a specific id?

JS:

```
var array = [];
var lastid = 0;

  function add(){
    var task = document.getElementById("task").value;
    array.push(task);

    var text = document.createTextNode(task);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id','task'+lastid);
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
    btn.setAttribute('onClick','remove("'+'task'+lastid+'")');
    li.appendChild(text);
    li.appendChild(btn);
    lastid=+1;
    document.getElementById("myUl").appendChild(li);
  };

  function remove(itemid){
    var task = document.getElementById(itemid);
    document.getElementById("myUl").removeChild(task);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input id="task">
<button onclick="add()">add</button>
<ul id="myUl"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small mistake.
"lastid=+1" is not increment but assignment operation. You assign to lastid value "+1".
It's allowed to add sign before number values.

If you want to increment you should use increment operator "lastid+=1"

Other option.
If you want to delete current item without incrementing element id you can get current element from global object "this.event."
For example you can modify your remove function this way:

```
function remove(){
  var task = this.event.currentTarget.parentNode;
  document.getElementById("myUl").removeChild(task);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think I meant to add last +=1 instead of the other way around, thank you for pointing this out. Without that increment operator, clicking the removal button for (for example) list item #4 results in the removal of the uppermost items in the list. So, what is it about an increment operator that enables targeting of a specific item?